# Why does str(077) turn into "63"

Tags: python

Had to create a function that generates random phone numbers.

```
from string import digits
from random import choice 

def random_phone_number():
    number = str(077) + ''.join(choice(digits) for _ in range(8))
    return number

print random_phone_number() // prints 6344940334
```

I expected phone number to start with 077 but instead it starts with 63. Whats the deal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because a number starting with a zero means that it's in base 8, i.e. octal form.

77 is then interpreted as 7 * 8 + 7 = 56 + 7 = 63 in decimal.

From reading your code I'm not entierly sure what's going on (the title mentions a call to `str(077)` but I'm not seeing that), but I still think this is relevant.

Comment: Did you try the OP's code? I found that it prints strings starting with `'077'`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Yes, confusing. I suspect a mis-paste from the OP.

Comment: Yea, i copied the code with "077" cause i changed my code already. I edited the post now. I hope the down votes are for the mistake. And that question wasnt stupid :D thanks for the answer.